# Accessing scala object fields from java

Tags: java, scala, interop

I'm having trouble accessing the fields of a scala object from java.

Scala:

```
object TestObject {
  val field = 5 
}
```

Java:

```
public class JavaTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int i = TestObject.field;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
[error] JavaTest.java: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : variable field
[error] location: class TestObject
[error]     int i = TestObject.field;
```

Comment: To see all the public members use: `javap -classpath <classpath> <classname>`. E.g. `javap -classpath target/scala-2.9.1.final/classes TestObject`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Scala fields are private variables with a getter of the same name to preserve immutability.

```
public class JavaTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int i = TestObject.field();
  }
}
```