# Are Scala "object" variables not visible from java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing scala object fields from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788363/accessing-scala-object-fields-from-java)

I have this scala object

```
object Foo {
  val TOTAL = 10
  def totalMethod = 10
}
```

When I do this on java code:

```
System.out.println(Foo.totalMethod());
```

it works, but when I do

```
System.out.println(Foo.TOTAL);
```

It doesn't:

```
    [error] /Users/pfernand/Projects/foo/Whatever.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [error] symbol  : variable TOTAL
    [error] location: class Foo
    [error]         System.out.println(Foo.TOTAL);
    [error]
```

Comment: It's a duplicate indeed. Sorry, but I couldn't find the answer by googling :(

Answer (score 4):

The Scala compiler generates a parameterless method with the name of the field.
You can use

```
System.out.println(Foo.TOTAL());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
System.out.println(Foo.TOTAL());
```

Scala makes fields private and provides a "getter" method (using the same name) for access.

Answer (score 1):

The above will create a getter, which you should be able to access with `Foo.TOTAL()`. There's no way to access the field directly from Java, AFAIK.

Comment: That's right, the field is private.